# How can I setup headers directives on my app engine?

Tags: python, headers, google-app-engine, flask

So I was scanning my website for vulnerabilities and I found this one but I don't know how can I fixed it in the google cloud app engine:

I really don't know where I should include the header directives but I suppose it's in the app.yaml but I don't know what "Tag" to use to set up the headers or if its a CloudFlare side patch.

Here is the URL for the How to Fix:

https://wiki.crashtest-security.com/enable-security-headers?utm_source=Crashtest%20Security%20Suite&utm_medium=Suite

I tried to search the internet for answers but I couldn't find anyone that fixes this issue.

I'm using a flask with python 3.7.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

---

*Please note, this answer is based on documentation examples and is untested.*

---

Based on the [Google Cloud Documentation for app.yaml](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/config/appref) and the [site you linked to with the desired security headers](https://wiki.crashtest-security.com/enable-security-headers), you may wish to try the following e.g.:

```
handlers:
- url: /images
  static_dir: static/images
  http_headers:
    # X-Foo-Header: foo
    # X-Bar-Header: bar value 
    strict-transport-security: max-age=31536000
    x-frame-options: deny
    x-xss-protection: 1; mode=block
    X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
    content-security-policy: default-src 'self'
    referrer-policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

You will likely need to set these individually for each of the general URLs that your app uses. If you run into any issues, you can also try the "capitalized" versions:

```
Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=31536000
X-Frame-Options: deny
X-XSS-Protection: 1; mode=block
X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
Content-Security-Policy: default-src 'self'
Referrer-Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

Note that you may want to be careful setting the `Strict-Transport-Security` header, as it will effectively disable HTTP access to the site. Even if you remove the header, you will likely need to take extra steps to clear it from your browser.